# Dovecot not honoring dovecot.conf (auth failure)?

Tags: email, authentication, dovecot

My `dovecot.conf` has the following entry:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login digest-md5 cram-md5
```

Dovecot is using the `dovecot.conf`:

```
$ dovecnf -n
# 2.1.7 /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

When I attempt to run `imapsync`, I receive an error:

```
Host2: <host> says it has NO CAPABILITY for AUTHENTICATE LOGIN
```

`imapsync` also dumps the helo string, and it is missing:

```
Host2: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ ... STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
```

I've restarted the dovecot service with `service dovecot restart` and even rebooted the machine.

There is nothing reported in any on the `/var/log/mail.<level>` log files. They are literally empty (even after sending a test email with `mail`).

Any ideas why `dovecot` is not honoring the setting in its config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have the `disable_plaintext_auth` directive set somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I checked both Postfix's `main.cf` and Dovecot's `dovecot.conf` Neither use the directive. OT: I've been to Amazon, and they don't have a book on Dovecot. Are you aware of any good treatments on its configuration and administration? I've spent 2 days on blog posts and mini HowTos, and they are not helpful. (They are not helpful because of my own ignorance. I really need something that explains the pieces and then assembles the pieces).

Comment: @noloader What distribution are you using? The directive should be somewhere, if only for documentation purposes. On Debian, it is in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`. I don't know of any good books, sorry. If you're having other trouble with dovecot, try to find me on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Comment: Debian 7.4, i686. Someone would probably make a small fortune if they wrote a book on Postfix + Dovecot since its so popular. I would bet O'Reilly would have an interest.

Comment: The system I'm looking at is a Wheezy as well, so, if you're using the official packages as I do, then you should also have the `conf.d` directory (where all your configuration should go anyway, the dovecot.conf is just an entry point that shouldn't be touched).

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I'm going to jump on the Dovecot mailing list. I would feel bad spraying you with an endless stream of questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "the dovecot.conf is just an entry point that shouldn't be touched..." - btw, others did not get the memo. Nearly every blog and mini-HowTo has folks modifying `dovecot.conf`. (I'm not arguing with you about it - you are probably right).

Comment: Last comment... Make that a book on Postfix + Dovecot + Clam + Spam Assassin. Ultimately, that's what I'd like to get running. If you have Subject Matter Expertise, you might want to check out [Writing for O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/intro.csp).

Comment: @noloader: That is due to several reasons. It is the core configuration file of Dovecot and, thus, will always work and it's the only file the core code actually cares about. On Debian, a different configuration architecture is deployed, but only in recent versions. Those blog posts might simply be outdated. The reason not to edit the core configuration files is that you don't want to create conflicts that happen when you update the package and the configuration files have changed. You just put *your* configuration into other files that aren't touched by the update process.